# Strange PHP DOMDocument Warning

Tags: php, windows, iis, domdocument

This code below gives me a DOMDocument Warning and I wonder why. Is there anything I can do to fix it, or not display this particular warning? I'm running php on windows xp and iis.

```
$content = "<html><body><p>'HTTP_REFERER' => 'http://localhost/?table=event_occurrence_person&LB1ID='</p></body></html>";
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($content);
```

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 1 in...

Comment: try putting the $content in single quotes. Its possible that HTTP_REFERER is being considered a constant.

Comment: @Way No, that's not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your XML is malformed.

- `=>` must be escaped to `=&gt;` *(optional, not blocking)*
- `&LB1ID` must be escaped to `&amp;LB1ID` *(raises your warning)*

Answer (score 3):

There's a bare `&` in the HTML. `&` signals the start of an HTML entity, a bare `&` needs to be represented as the entity `&amp;`. That's where the warning comes from.

You can silence warnings using `@`:

```
@$dom->loadHTML($content);
```

If you have full control over the HTML, you should *not* silence warnings. If you are parsing other people's HTML, you may have no choice.